Record Update on Another Object In Flow
I am working on the following assignment and can't figure out why my flow is not working.
Whenever vitals are recorded on a Visit record, update the "Latest..." fields on the Contact record
Criteria
Any of the following Visit fields are updated
Heart Rate
Temperature
Height
Weight
The Date on the visit is greater than or equal to the "Latest Visit" date on the Contact
Visit Status = Complete
Actions
Update "Latest Visit" on the Contact to match the "Date" on the Visit
Update the "Latest..." fields on the Contact to match the appropriate fields on the Visit:
Heart Rate
Temperature
Height
Weight





Um, what assignment? Can you show where you set the field values - [edit] to add it.

Uploaded screenshots of all the elements. Thanks in advance
